# How to change URL structure for custom post type in wordpress? Custom taxonomy + custom Post name

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I want to change the url structure for custom post type

post type --> **movies**

This url structure **sitename.com/movies/post-name** need to change **sitename.com/custom-taxonomy/movies/post-name**

> /%customtaxonomy%/%customposttype%/%postname%/

Comment: Although your structure is the other way round, setting `rewrite` to `%custom_tax%/movies` should work just as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create your own rewrite rule for that custom post type.

Example creating a rewrite rule :

```
function custom_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $feed_rules = array(
        'reviews/(.+)/(.+)'      =>  'index.php?post_type=movies&taxonomy_name='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&post_name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
// refresh/flush permalinks in the dashboard if this is changed in any way
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite' );
```